# Is there any formal studies of why philosophers think a certain way or focus on certain topics?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, history, cognitive-psychology, cognitive-bias

In other words, I looking for a formal study of philosophers and their thinking as the object to be studied.

Parts of what philosophers think about is influenced by history, of course. It is no surprise that philosophers in the ages spent a lot of time thinking about god.

I’m most interested in the psychological and cognitive aspects, though. Why do philosophers prefer 0/1 concepts, for instance? Why do some of them like one kind of argument more than another? To what extent do they engage in confirmation-bias-driven reasoning?

Comment: See [Heidegren-Lundberg, Towards a Sociology of Philosophy](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0001699309357831), and references therein, also  [Strevens's Psychology of Philosophy reading list](http://www.strevens.org/classes/psychphil16/PsychPhil16-Syllabus.pdf). [Herzberg's book The Psychology Of Philosophers](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.221746/page/n9/mode/2up) is a classical study.

Comment: @Conifold thank you, this is very helpful!